# SKStoreReviewController block the current view

Tags: ios, swift, rating, skstorereviewcontroller

I use SKStoreReviewController in my viewController, the rating dialog appears but when I select Not now and close the dialog the current view stays blocked and doesn't allow interaction.

In my viewDidLoad I added this code:

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *),
    let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
} else {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
}
```

Any ideas?